# Facebook: Expired access tokens and realtime

Tags: facebook, real-time, token

I am looking for help/advice on handling expired tokens (eg. user changes password) in conjunction with the realtime api.  I have read the following http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/
but it appears to require a user session. Currently the only solution I can see is detecting the OAuth error and informing the user via another means such as email that they need to go through the app authorisation process again.

Comment: Have you tried as like in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

you can renew the fb access token, there is the feasible solution for this, kindly have look into [how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/) here, you can see the answer in `Solution (for all scenarios)` section